# JLabel Width Independent from Text Length

Tags: java, text, jpanel, long-integer, jlabel

I have a JLabel in a horizontally re-sizable JPanel. The JLabel auto re-sizes its width to fit the JPanel. If I insert a long line of text (such as "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") the JLabel doesn't truncate the text. Instead, the width re-sizes to fit the text, causing also an ugly re-sizing of the JPanel.
Instead, I want my text to be truncated with an elipse (...). The JLabel width must not inherit from the text's length but only from the JPanel width.

Comment: What layout is the containing JPanel using?  If just the default FlowLayout, consider experimenting with other layouts such as BorderLayout, or BoxLayout.

Comment: I'm using GroupLayout, i don't think that it's a layout problem

Comment: Are you 100% sure?  I beg to differ as in my experience this is the key issue.  Do you well understand GroupLayout as well as the other layout managers because this knowledge is essentially to be able to make this call.

Comment: And I second jzd's recommendation to post an SSCCE.  You can read up on this here: http://sscce.org

Comment: I tried to create a SSCCE but it's very complicated... it's a complicated project :(
could a video of the problem be usefull?

Comment: While it may be a complex program, your current problem is pretty straight-forward and is a simple matter of creating a small app that demonstrates the problem. I would first though recommend you try to use different layout managers to see what effect it will have.  Are you familiar with the commonly used managers such as FlowLayout, BorderLayout, GridLayout, BoxLayout, and GridBagLayout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following:

```
final JLabel label = ...
...
label.setText("prototype text to define size");
final Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();
label.setMinimumSize(size);
label.setPreferredSize(size);
...
label.setText(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different layout or set a max size on the JLabel.

Comment: i need that layout (GroupLayout) and i don't want to set a max size on the jlabel because i want that his width is the same as the jpanel (the jpanel is resizable)

Comment: In that case, can you post an SSCCE?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable 'Horizontal Resizable' when you define a max- and preferedsize